# Can I change the passphrase of a private key that has been encrypted?

Tags: private, key, encrypted

When importing the secret key for the fundraiser I was asked to enter a passphrase, is it possible to change it, if so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The passphrase set during the fundraiser can not be changed. After you have entered the fundraiser details, some wallets will store your private key in a keystore file encrypted with a password. In this case the password can always be changed. If there is no built-in function for this you can always enter your fundraiser details again and create a new keystore file with a new password. Your wallet can now be accessed from both keystore files, so the old keystore file can be removed.

The reason that you are asked for the password for every action is that the wallet does not store your private key unencrypted, so it will sometimes need you to enter the password in order to decrypt the private key.

Answer (score 1):

The passphrase used for fundraiser wallets contribute to the makeup of the secret key, so it's impossible to change it (these passwords aren't actually used for encryption). If you believe your wallet details may have been compromised, you should create a new key and transfer your XTZ.

Comment: No, I mean, after importing the fundraiser key I was asked 2 times for a new passphrase to encrypt my secret keys if I can remember. Every action asks me about this passphrase.

Comment: Are you using a tezos-client or another wallet - please clarify? You can change the encryption password/passphrase with relative ease but the method differs depending on what you are using as a wallet.

Comment: I am using the tezos-client, but I think I would reimport the founder key to change the keystore file. thanks anyway